# Regex query to remove character(s) from lines that has a phrase

Tags: regex

I'm trying to convert my DDL's from Oracle to Postgres but I'm having a problem with double quote characters. I want to remove double quotes from each and every line which contains "CREATE TABLE " phrase. For example I want this: `CREATE TABLE "ILIKEMEMES"` to be converted to this: `CREATE TABLE ILIKEMEMES`  but I don't want line `("ID" VARCHAR(255)` to change either. I'm doing this on Notepad++ so Python scripts wouldn't be my first choice of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \bCREATE TABLE "(.*?)"
Replace: CREATE TABLE $1
```

This will target only create table statements having a table name which appears in double quotes.